# Javascript: Global point to local space of HTMLElement (transform aware)

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looking for a way to convert global mouse coordinates to the local coordinates of an HTMLElement whose parent elements make use of (CSS) transform e.g. scale.

Actually exactly like ActionScript 3's [DisplayObject#globalToLocal](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal()).